# Get proj4 parameters from EPSG in C++

Tags: proj, c++, epsg, request

I have the EPSG number of the projection and I want to use proj4 to get the projection descriptive string (like `+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`)

I want to use proj4 and no html request like http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/EPSG/proj4/ because the tool has to work without internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The International Association of Oil & Gas Producers (IOGP) EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset is available for download through their web site ~ http://www.epsg.org/.

However, if you have proj4 the EPSG codes should be available in your installation in a `epsg` file at a location:

```
\bin\proj\SHARE\epsg
```

If you have proj6 the EPSG codes are contained in a sqlite3 database file `proj.db` in a location like:

```
\bin\proj6\share\proj.db
```